# Spark textFileStream not reading files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Im trying to get the spark streaming to work. But it doesen't read any files i put in the directory.
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext("local[*]", "StreamTest")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
    ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

    files = ssc.textFileStream("file:///ApacheSpark/MLlib_testing/Streaming/data")

    words = files.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
    pairs = words.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
    wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
    print "Oled siin ??"

    wordCounts.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Everything works but no files are read from the folder. The print command is executed once and that is when the application is starting. What am i doing wrong?

Im on windows 10 and using spark 1.6.2. Couldnt get spark 2.0.0 running.

Edit 1
Im adding some console log output.

```
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1473237417000 ms
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO JobGenerator: Checkpointing graph for time 1473237417000 ms
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO DStreamGraph: Updating checkpoint data for time 1473237417000 ms
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO DStreamGraph: Updated checkpoint data for time 1473237417000 ms
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO CheckpointWriter: Submitted checkpoint of time 1473237417000 ms writer queue
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO CheckpointWriter: Saving checkpoint for time 1473237417000 ms to file 'file:/C:/Users/Marko/Desktop/ApacheSpark/MLlib_testing/Streaming/checkpoint/checkpoint-1473237417000'
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO CheckpointWriter: Deleting file:/C:/Users/Marko/Desktop/ApacheSpark/MLlib_testing/Streaming/checkpoint/checkpoint-1473233874000.bk
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO CheckpointWriter: Checkpoint for time 1473237417000 ms saved to file 'file:/C:/Users/Marko/Desktop/ApacheSpark/MLlib_testing/Streaming/checkpoint/checkpoint-1473237417000', took 6071 bytes and 72 ms
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO MapOutputTrackerMaster: Size of output statuses for shuffle 0 is 82 bytes
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393) with 3 output partitions
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 3 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393)
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 2)
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 3 (PythonRDD[22] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43), which has no missing parents
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 6.1 KB, free 15.8 KB)
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.5 KB, free 19.3 KB)
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on localhost:59483 (size: 3.5 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 3 missing tasks from ResultStage 3 (PythonRDD[22] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43)
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 3.0 with 3 tasks
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 1, localhost, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 1986 bytes)
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 2, localhost, partition 2,PROCESS_LOCAL, 1986 bytes)
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3, localhost, partition 3,PROCESS_LOCAL, 1986 bytes)
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 1)
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 2)
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3)
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 0 blocks
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 0 blocks
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 9 ms
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 0 blocks
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 10 ms
16/09/07 11:36:57 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 23 ms
16/09/07 11:36:58 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 3 ms
16/09/07 11:36:58 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1473237418000 ms:
```

Comment: Any log output from the executors?

Comment: @LiMuBei Added console log output for 1 iteration over the folder. Always the same do i add file or not nothing changes.

Comment: Which folder exactly are you putting the files into? The log indicates that it prefixes with your user directory automatically. Just to make sure it's not something super simple.. Additionally, what do logs from executors tell you? You can get them via Spark web UI.

Comment: Folder is in the same place as the streaming.py file. Logs dont seem to give any errors everything is just waiting.

Comment: @LiMuBei i would like to make the folder just data, without the full path. But when i put file:data or something like that i get error. I think the problem is that it is looking to the wrong place. But how can i tell it that the data folder is in the same place as the .py file?

Comment: Are you putting files into `C:/Users/Marko/Desktop/ApacheSpark/MLlib_testing/Streaming/data`? Because it seems from the logs that this would be the folder it's looking into.

Comment: Yes im putting files into that folder. But it gets nothing from it. could it be the file: prefix? Or it cant read .txt or it cant see .txt ?

Comment: @LiMuBei i have tried everything i could find, nothing changes. It seems streaming localli cant work on windows.